# How to pass value in user control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

Hi I have set a value in <%= MutlipleB %> and below is my Usercontrol calling in .aspx page.
Let say <%= MutlipleB %> is in string format and i have set a value as "1" or "2" i.e. set dynamically from code side. I want to pass this value in user control. But it is passing value as <%= MutlipleB %> not "1" or "2".
How could I pass my proper value?

```
<eu:EASIUp ID="myeasiup" runat="server" Quantity="-1" CanBeZero="false" NameID='<%= MutlipleB %>'></eu:EASIUp>
```

or Tried passing value as

```
<%# MutlipleB %> / <%= this.MutlipleB %> / <%# this.MutlipleB %>//Still not working
```

User control code

```
private string _nameID="0";
public string NameID
{
    get
    {
        return _nameID.ToString();
    }
    set { _nameID = value; }
}
```

Set value in <%= MutlipleB %> as below in aspx.cs code

```
private string _multipleB = "0";
public string MutlipleB
{
    get { return _multipleB; }
    set { _multipleB = value; }
}
```

how can I retrive value on user control side

**The main reason to pass this value is on UserControl we are generating dynamic control and the id of this control should be generated related to the value i m passing**

Answer (score 0):

Give your User Control a public property.

```
public partial class myCustomControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string NameID { get; set; }
}
```

And you can then set or get the value from the aspx page code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myeasiup.NameID = "myString";
}
```

Comment: Till now to fix i had done my code as 
                                <eu:EASIUp ID="myeasiup" runat="server" Quantity="-1" CanBeZero="false"></eu:EASIUp>
                                 <%= MutlipleB.ToString()=="0"? myeasiup.NameID=="0":myeasiup.NameID=="1" %>  but need exact code

Comment: I want this things to be done on .aspx side and not from .aspx.cs side, Can u help me out?

Comment: I don't think you can. It is possible to set properties dynamically `NameID='<%= MutlipleB %>'`, but due to the page load cycle they won't be usable in the user control (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Open your user control's code behind page (`FILENAME.ascx.cs`). There you add below property.

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

So, overall your code page be like:

```
namespace YOUR.NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class CLASS_NAME : UserControl
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        ... // REST OF CODE

    }
}
```

You can simply pass data to your code behind like below in where you are using user control:

```
<TAG_PREFIX:CLASS_NAME runat="server" Value="YOUR_DATA" ID="SomeId"/>
```

Or from the code behind like below:

```
SomeId.Value = "YOUR_DATA";
```

Hope this helps.